# Show all markers with Google Map sdk iOS Xamarin

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, xamarin, markers

I want to show all my markers on the Google Map. I am using the `Google map sdk` component from the Component store. I can show a single marker fine. But i want to Show all the markers which I have in a list. I did find solutions which suggested to use `GMSCoordinateBounds`, but I could not find it with the sdk I am using. I know that i have to use the `CameraUpdate.FitBounds()`.

I have implemented the below code, but this only shows the last marker in the list only.

```
private float CalculateMarkerInclusiveZoomLevel(MapView mapView, List<Marker> markers, int minVisible)
        {
            try
            {
                var bounds =
                  new CoordinateBounds(mapView.Projection.VisibleRegion);
                var initialZoomLevel = mapView.Camera.Zoom;
                markerInclusiveZoomLevel = initialZoomLevel;
            var count = markers.Count(
              m => bounds.ContainsCoordinate(m.Position));

            while (count < markers.Count && count < minVisible)
            {
                // Each zoom level doubles the viewable area
                var latGrowth =
                  (bounds.NorthEast.Latitude - bounds.SouthWest.Latitude) / 2;
                var lngGrowth =
                  (bounds.NorthEast.Longitude - bounds.SouthWest.Longitude) / 2;
                markerInclusiveZoomLevel--;

                bounds = new CoordinateBounds(
                   new CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                       bounds.NorthEast.Latitude + latGrowth,
                       bounds.NorthEast.Longitude + lngGrowth),
                   new CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                       bounds.SouthWest.Latitude - latGrowth,
                       bounds.SouthWest.Longitude - lngGrowth));

                count = markers.Count(m => bounds.ContainsCoordinate(m.Position));
                return markerInclusiveZoomLevel;
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }

        return markerInclusiveZoomLevel;
    }
```

How do I do it. Any examples will be useful.

Answer (score 1):

> but this only shows the last marker in the list only.

Well yeah. In your `while` loop, you're returning as the final statement.

You'll likely want to move that return statement out of your `while` loop. So:

```
private float CalculateMarkerInclusiveZoomLevel(MapView mapView, List<Marker> markers, int minVisible)
{
    try
    {
        var bounds = new CoordinateBounds(mapView.Projection.VisibleRegion);
        var initialZoomLevel = mapView.Camera.Zoom;
        markerInclusiveZoomLevel = initialZoomLevel;
        var count = markers.Count(m => bounds.ContainsCoordinate(m.Position));

        while (count < markers.Count && count < minVisible)
        {
            // Each zoom level doubles the viewable area
            var latGrowth =
              (bounds.NorthEast.Latitude - bounds.SouthWest.Latitude) / 2;
            var lngGrowth =
              (bounds.NorthEast.Longitude - bounds.SouthWest.Longitude) / 2;
            markerInclusiveZoomLevel--;

            bounds = new CoordinateBounds(
               new CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                   bounds.NorthEast.Latitude + latGrowth,
                   bounds.NorthEast.Longitude + lngGrowth),
               new CLLocationCoordinate2D(
                   bounds.SouthWest.Latitude - latGrowth,
                   bounds.SouthWest.Longitude - lngGrowth));

            count = markers.Count(m => bounds.ContainsCoordinate(m.Position));
        }
        return markerInclusiveZoomLevel;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return markerInclusiveZoomLevel;
}
```

Comment: Hi, I tried doing the same initially, but the return statement is never reached.